# Regex command, OR doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have part of the following text that I'm reading with C#

> "I have to see your driver’s license and print you an ID tag before I can send you through," he said in a flat, automatic sort of way, staring at the horns with blank-eyed fascination.

I'm reading in some lines of this one book, and I'd like to create strings out of all the words, including those with apostrophes. I'd like to split the lines based on non word characters, but I want apostrophes to be included with the word characters, so I ultimately get a list of strings with just words, so that the word "driver's" is together.

I'm using sublime to test out the expressions, but when I do `(\W+|\')`, apostrophes are still captured. I don't want to split something like "you'd" into two string. `\W+` is perfect, but I'd just like to include apostrophes. How could I do that?

Comment: Does it have to be in Sublime? There's a super-efficient way to do it in Perl and PHP.

Comment: Oh no, I'm just using Sublime to test the regular expressions, but my goal is to use C# to read the line and break it up into strings based on the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a regex matching "between" the words:

```
[^\w']+
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that do the same as \W+ ? The problem is that I'd like the apostrophes to be included with the words, but no other character.

Comment: `[^\w]+` would be equivalent to `\W+`. But I included the apostrophe in the characters that are excluded from the class, so it'll only count characters that are not part of words AND are not the apostrophe.

Comment: Oh, I see, didn't notice that, but in sublime, the apostrophe is selected along with the other characters like periods? Is that just sublime?

Comment: I used an ASCII quote `'` but what you want is actually an apostrophe `’`. Add both in the class and you should get what you want...

Comment: WOW PERFECT! I can't believe I didn't notice that. Actually I'm a novice so that's expected lol, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try String.Split: example follows

```
string _input ="I have to see your driver’s license and print you an ID tag before I can send you through";
string[] _words = _input.Split(' ');
```

In case you want to remove other characters, for example: single quote (apostrophe) "'" and comma "," and use Replace(), like:

```
_input = _input.Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace(",",String.Empty);
string[] _words = _input.Split(' ');
```

You can also use Regex, but its performance is worse than of these methods (if it does matter).

Also, you can try as an example my 'semantic analyzer' app at: http://webinfocentral.com/TECH/SemanticAnalyzer.aspx . It's doing all that stuff and much more (characters to exclude are listed at the left pane). Rgds,

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that also be including periods, quotation marks, comma's and all the above? I'd just like the plain words, without that extra stuff

Comment: If I use this method, wouldn't I have to know what I want to remove? All I know is what I want to keep lol, just letters and apostrophes, and I'd like to automatically exclude the other stuff.

Comment: Then don't include Replace("'", String.Empty) and specify ";", ":", ".", "!" to remove

Comment: But I don't know all the characters I'd like to remove, I only know what I want to keep... I can't specify what I don't know lol, the periods and commas were just examples or the many characters to exclude.